# why qtnetworkaccessmanager don't go to authenticationRequired

Tags: authentication, qnetworkaccessmanager, owncloud

I am creating an application that is mentioned to connect to an instance of on owncloud server but i can't find why it doesn't connect to the server .Instead of that the reply i get to the login screen and i get the html code for it

this is the code responsible for the connection

```
//the network request and reply
          QNetworkAccessManager * manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
          QUrl url (url1);
          manager->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
          connect(manager, SIGNAL(authenticationRequired(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*)),
                      SLOT(provideAuthenication(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*)));
          connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)),
                  this, SLOT(result(QNetworkReply *)));
```

the reply code

```
void Login::result(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    reply->deleteLater();

     if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
         // Get the http status code
         int v = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt();
         if (v >= 200 && v < 300) // Success
         {
             qDebug()<<"Here we got the final reply";
             QString replyText = reply->readAll();
             qDebug()<<replyText;
         }
         else if (v >= 300 && v < 400) // Redirection
         {
             qDebug()<<"Get the redirection url";
             QUrl newUrl = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute).toUrl();
             // Because the redirection url can be relative,
             // we have to use the previous one to resolve it
             newUrl = reply->url().resolved(newUrl);

             QNetworkAccessManager *manager = reply->manager();
             QNetworkRequest redirection(newUrl);
             QNetworkReply *newReply = manager->get(redirection);
             QString replyText = newReply->readAll();
             qDebug()<<replyText;
             return; // to keep the manager for the next request
         }
     }
     else
     {
         // Error
         qDebug()<<reply->errorString();
     }

     reply->manager()->deleteLater();
 }
```

could you help me figure out why i get the login screen instead of authentication ?

Comment: it appears to be a problem in the url !

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `connect()` before calling `manager->get()` otherwise when the authentication required signal is triggered, there might not be any slots present to call to handle that signal.

Try this instead:

```
QNetworkAccessManager * manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();
QUrl url (url1);
connect(manager, SIGNAL(authenticationRequired(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*)),
    SLOT(provideAuthenication(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*)));
connect(manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)),
    this, SLOT(result(QNetworkReply *)));
manager->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
```